# Powershell splatting inserting extra characters

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to use splatting to insert some arguments in a command. I can't get the splatting to format the argument in such a way that it gets accepted when executed.

Currently its inserting a ": " (colon and a space) into the argument which is causing a syntax error.

This is what I have -

```
$UserMem = @("148712","148684")
$params = @{}

$params["--field=USER: Members="] =$UserMem

write-host @params
```

The output from that is –

```
---field=USER: Members=: 148712 148684
```

Note it has "Members=: " where it should be "Members="

It should be –

```
---field=USER: Members=148712 148684
```

Any thoughts on how I can prevent the extraneous colon & space from appearing?

Thanks

Comment: That's the way splatting works.  It's for passing named parameters to a Powershell script, function, or script block and conforms to Powershell's convention for passing named parameters.  If you're passing it to something else, you need to use a different method.

Comment: Sending the data `Write-Host` is probably not the best way to test either. Are you having an issue with your real reason for doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This gives you the output you want

```
$UserMem = @("148712","148684")
$params = @{}

$params["--field=USER: Members="] =$UserMem

foreach ($key in $params.Keys)
{
    Write-Host -Verbose $key $params[$key]
}
```

Comment: downvote? question was "Any thoughts on how I can prevent the extraneous colon & space from appearing?". I didn't apply any hacks or change the HashTable object

Comment: Thanks. I think this is going to give me what I'm after.

Answer (score 1):

Just change line 4 to this format:

```
$params =  "---field=USER: Members=$UserMem"
```

This will give you the output you desire.

```
> write-host @params 
---field=USER: Members=: 148712 148684
```

I'm not sure why you were using the format you had previously.  It's much simpler to just approach setting a variable from this perspective.

Answer (score 1):

@mjolinor has a point about using write-host, so lets use custom function instead:

```
$arr = @(10,20)
$params = @{}
$params["par"] = $arr

function splattest {
    "args0: [$($args[0])]"
    "args1: [$($args[1])]"
}

splattest @params
```

The result is:

```
args0: [-par:]
args1: [10 20]
```

No space here, so it's not because of splatting. Now execute this:

```
@(1,2)
write-host @(3,4)
```

result:

```
1
2
3 4
```

and that's just the way write-host is printing arrays: all elements in one line separated by space.

As of `-par:`, it's like @Matt said: that's how splatting works :). 
Usually `:` is used for manipulating switch parameters programatically, like this: `Get-ChildItem -File:$True`, but it also works with options (ie named arguments): `Get-Process -Name:explorer`.
I suppose splatter adds colon just to be consistent.

Answer (score -1):

Bit of a hack, but

```
$UserMem = @("148712","148684")
$params = @{}

$params["--field=USER"] ="Members=$UserMem"

write-host @params
```

Gives you

```
---field=USER: Members=148712 148684
```

mjolinor's comment to your post is the reason this is a hack.  You should probably choose a different method if your parameters need to get any  more complex than this.